# Descriptions of heterogenous datatypes

Tags: agda, reference-request, inductive-type, universe

When attempting to describe the datatype as appearing in [my previous question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/proving-strict-positivity-in-agda/), using indexed descriptions in style of The Gentle Art of Levitation to describe this datatype (using Agda for examples):

```hs
data Val {Γ : Ctxt} : {τ : Ty Γ} -> (Γ ⊢ τ) -> Set where
    ✶Val : ∀{x : Γ ⊢ ✶ Γ } -> Atom x -> Val x
    UVal : ∀{n} -> {x : Γ ⊢ U n} -> Atom x -> Val x
    ElVal : ∀{n} {t' : Γ ⊢ U n} {t : Γ ⊢ El t'} -> Atom t -> Val t
    LiftVal : ∀ {τ} {z : Γ ⊢ Lift τ} -> Atom z -> Val z
    ΠVal : ∀{τ₁} {τ₂} {t₁ : Γ ⊢ Π τ₁ τ₂}
       -> (
          (Γ' : RCtxt Γ)
          -> (t₂ : (Γ ++ Γ') ⊢ (τ₁ / wk⋆ Γ'))
          -> (v₂ : Val t₂) -- this is the not strictly positive position
          -> Val {Γ = Γ ++ Γ'} (app (t₁ /⊢ wk⋆ _) t₂)
          )
     -- ^ this is the position with a different parameter, but still strictly positive
      -> Val t₁
    _∷ˢ_ : ∀{Γ¹} {τ¹} {t¹ : Γ¹ ⊢ τ¹}
        {τ² : Ty Γ} {t² : Γ ⊢ τ²} -> Val t¹
        -> (t¹ ≈⊢ t²) -> Val  t²
```

And the indexed syntax of indexed description being:

```hs
data IDesc (I : Set) : Set₁ where
  var : (i : I) -> _
  k : (A : Set) -> _
  _×D_ : (D1 : IDesc I) -> (D2 : IDesc I) -> _
  ΣD ΠD : (S : Set) -> (T : S -> IDesc I) -> _
```

I run into an issue that the wishful application of `var` fails in the pointed out strictly positive position, unless we index also by `Ctxt`, as `var` can not take parameters without them being part of the index. We can still apply well-founded argument in that position, but given it is strictly positive it should not have to be the case. This leads me to the following.
Has a universe of descriptions been studied, where heterogeneous applications of parameters do not have to be encoded as indices, i.e. the distinction between heterogeneous parameters and indices is kept?

Edit: Having parsed more of the paper Generic programming with indexed functors by Löh and Magalhães suggested by Albert ten Napel. I would like to note the following: While in this paper we are given a description systematically split on both parameters (I) and indices (O), I cannot see a way to encode a dependency between I and O. If anyone has any suggestions how to do that I think I might be able to brainstorm an answer from there.

Edit 2: Descriptions, where indices can depend on parameters, appear in Yorick Sijsling's thesis [Generic programming with
ornaments and dependent types](https://studenttheses.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/20.500.12932/23661/thesis_color.pdf) in form of ConDesc in Listing 5.1, p. 34 (36), so now what's left is a generic account or specific account for Val of the translation of non-regular datatype to a small index as done for a concrete case of Finger trees as in https://gallais.github.io/blog/non-regular-parameters.html.
Anyone knows of such a generic account?

Comment: Check out "Generic programming with indexed functors".

Comment: @AlberttenNapel I have been reading through it, while it seems like it should provide a solution that works I am struggling with figuring out how to encode a position like the strictly positive one in Val, i.e. the change in $\Gamma$ above. Do you maybe have some pointers about how to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that's called a non-regular parameter. Maybe the technique from https://gallais.github.io/blog/non-regular-parameters.html can be useful here? Also, I see now that you have a non-strictly positive occurrence of `Val`...so you cannot encode this datatype using the description in any case.

Comment: @AlberttenNapel thank you, the whole point of introducing descriptions for rest of the datatype is that it gives hope of taming the non-strictly positive occurence via well-founded recursion afterwards.